# bootstrap modal on top fixed positioned div

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

it seems my popup modal is not on top of everything. There is a div with fixed position. How can I make modal appear on top of fixed positioned div?

Fixed positioned div (header):

```
<div class="main-header">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                <div class="logo">
                    <h1>header</h1>
                </div> <!-- /.logo -->
            </div> <!-- /.col-md-4 -->
            <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-6">
                <div class="menu text-right hidden-sm hidden-xs">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#home"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#contact"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> Contact us</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div> <!-- /.menu -->
            </div> <!-- /.col-md-8 -->
        </div> <!-- /.row -->
    </div> <!-- /.container -->
</div>
```

Modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        I am pop up
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What z-index do each of these have? If you need the modal above your header then it's z-index should be bigger than the z-index of the header with at least one.

Comment: header's `z-index:9999` but z-index for modal is not working even with `z-index:99999`

Comment: In a similar situation I have used z-index: 1030 for `navbar`, the modal-backdrop has 1040 and the modal itself 1050. Look at the example bootstap it's providing for `navbar-fixed-top`

Comment: how do you "open" the modal window?